# PHP stop data from being echoed twice in loop

Tags: php

Consider the following simple code, which should stop the same value being echoed twice

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM events 
        WHERE event_date BETWEEN $curDate AND $date AND sport_type ='Rugby' 
        ORDER BY event_date ";

$lasttournament=""
echo'<select name="tournament" />';
 while($played>$venue){
   $tournament = $row['tournament'];

        if($tournament !== $lasttournament){
          $lasttournament = $tournament;
          echo'<option value="'.$tournament.'">'.$tournament.'</option>';           
         }//if 
      }//while
```

However my code is not giving the desired result, as you can see from image below.

[image]

Im obviously missing something, as each tournament should be displayed only once

Comment: fetch distinct record from sql query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with `distinct` if you need the `tournament` field only -

```
SELECT DISTINCT tournament FROM events 
    WHERE event_date BETWEEN $curDate AND $date AND sport_type ='Rugby'
    ORDER BY event_date
```

Or try with `group by` -

```
SELECT * FROM events 
    WHERE event_date BETWEEN $curDate AND $date AND sport_type ='Rugby'
    GROUP BY tournament 
    ORDER BY event_date
```

Comment: Ill give it a try and let you know

Answer (score 1):

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT tournament FROM events 
    WHERE event_date BETWEEN $curDate AND $date AND sport_type ='Rugby' 
    ORDER BY event_date ";
```

It seams you only need tournament from the sql and with this you will only get each tournament once.

Answer (score 1):

As other replied filtering values into sql using DISTINCT or GROUP BY is the right solution, you have a cleaner code and execute less iterations.

Anyway your code wasn't working because the variable $lasttournament is overwritten every cycle with the last value so your condition work only if the same values are consecutive each other.